# Comparing the siteURL variable to the current URL

Tags: templates, site-url

I am quite new to Expression Engine and am trying to get a handle on the template system. I have a nav with items that I want to set to active if they link to the current page

I have the link built like this so far:

```
<a href="{site_url}ranges/view/{url_title}">
   {menu_label}
</a>
```

The comparison I want to do is as follows:

if ((site_url + 'ranges/view' + url_title) == current_url) -> output class="active"

I have tried the following but I get a Parse/Syntax Error:

```
<a href="{site_url}ranges/view/{url_title}" {if (site_url + 'ranges/view/' + url_title) == current_url}class="active"{/if}>
   {menu_label}
</a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really want to compare the whole url? If not, it is easier to only compare the entry url_title and the url_title from the current url like this:

```
{if url_title == segment_3}class="active"{/if}
```

[Here](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/globals/url_segments.html) you can find more information about url segments.

Comment: You my friend, are a life saver :) Thanks for the link about segments, interesting feature

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you're getting parse errors as EE can't handle the "+" symbol, as it's for mathematical [addition](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/conditionals.html#mathematic-operators), not [concatenation](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/conditionals.html#string-concatenation-operator).

But fundamentally it won't work as {site_url} is parsed late, so can't be used in conditionals, see [here](http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf) for parse order details or more depth [here](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/template_engine.html) on the EE website.

I've written out the solution in [another Stack Exchange post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771165/conditional-using-site-url-is-always-false), which is to use a custom config variable, the alternative is replace site_url and hard code the protocol & domain, but that's not good if you have multiple environments.

Be aware of the downfalls of comparing url_title with segment_3 in a conditional, as this will match true even if there is a segment_4 in the url.